# AngularJs custom directive used twice in one controller with $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I have a controller which has a param called `refresh` and a $watch

```
app.controller (..., []) {
  $scope.refresh = false;

  $scope.$watch('refresh', function() {
            if(!$scope.refresh) return;
             $scope.apiCall(true);
            
   }, true);
}
```

I have a directive where `refresh` is used.

```
app.directive('dirA', () => {
  return {
    restricts: E,
    scope: {
      refresh: '=',
      .....
    },
    templateUrl: 'location of template',
    controller: [..., {
        function test() {
          $scope.refresh = false;
          // API call here
          fetch('/test', () => {
            this.refresh = true;
          )}
        }
    }]
  }
})
```

In my Controller's template I am using this directive twice like

```
<dirA refresh="refresh"/>
<dirA refresh="refresh"/>
```

Issue that I am facing is when `refresh` changes from first instance of directive, $watch is called but same is not happening from second instance.

I am pretty new to angularjs, Please help if possible

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a controller in a directive, you also need to bind the isolate scope of your directive using `bindToController`.

[Here is an article that explains `bindToController`](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html)

I also took the time to write [a plunkr](https://plnkr.co/plunk/gAqyZF1b02htmHAY) that demonstrates with the code you provided how this should probably look.